# .datalog format using Z3

Tags: python, z3, z3py, datalog

I'm trying to use the Z3 extension: muZ with fixed-point constraints following this tutorial: https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/fixedpoints.

**As marked in this tutorial, three different text-based input formats are accepted. The basic datalog is one of these accepted formats.**

I have programs of this form indicated in the tutorial:

```
Z 64

P0(x: Z) input

Gt0(x : Z, y : Z) input

R(x : Z) printtuples

S(x : Z) printtuples

Gt(x : Z, y : Z) printtuples

Gt(x,y) :- Gt0(x,y).

Gt(x,y) :- Gt(x,z), Gt(z,y).

R(x) :- Gt(x,_).

S(x) :- Gt(x,x0), Gt0(x,y), Gt0(y,z), P0(z).

Gt0("a","b").

Gt0("b","c").

Gt0("c","d").

Gt0("a1","b").

Gt0("b","a1").

Gt0("d","d1").

Gt0("d1","d").

P0("a1").
```

How can I parse these programs using Z3Py (or Z3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put that program text in a file (say `a.datalog`), you can directly call z3 on it. (Note that the extension has to be `datalog`).

When I do that, I get:

```
$ z3 a.datalog
Tuples in Gt:
        (x=a(0),y=b(1))
        (x=b(1),y=c(2))
        (x=c(2),y=d(3))
        (x=a1(4),y=b(1))
        (x=b(1),y=a1(4))
        (x=d(3),y=d1(5))
        (x=d1(5),y=d(3))
        (x=a(0),y=c(2))
        (x=a(0),y=a1(4))
        (x=b(1),y=d(3))
        (x=c(2),y=d1(5))
        (x=a1(4),y=c(2))
        (x=a1(4),y=a1(4))
        (x=b(1),y=b(1))
        (x=d(3),y=d(3))
        (x=d1(5),y=d1(5))
        (x=a(0),y=d(3))
        (x=a1(4),y=d(3))
        (x=b(1),y=d1(5))
        (x=a(0),y=d1(5))
        (x=a1(4),y=d1(5))
Tuples in R:
        (x=a(0))
        (x=b(1))
        (x=c(2))
        (x=a1(4))
        (x=d(3))
        (x=d1(5))
Tuples in S:
        (x=a(0))
        (x=a1(4))
Time: 3ms
Parsing: 0ms, other: 1ms
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes that's what im looking for. But How can i call the file .datalog in z3? ( I'm using Z3Py windows)

Comment: You'd put this in a file in your OS (use a text editor), and give it a name with the extension `.datalog`. Then call `z3` directly from the command line.

Comment: It Works now, Thank you.

Comment: what is the meaning of this lignes (input and printtuples) : P0(x: Z) input

Gt0(x : Z, y : Z) input

R(x : Z) printtuples

S(x : Z) printtuples

Gt(x : Z, y : Z) printtuples

Comment: the web site is currently under maintenance, is there any other reference where i can get a look at bddbddb syntax?

Comment: It works for me, try again. I should note that it doesn't look like the project is actively maintained. You might want to use one of the other input formats instead.

Comment: How to express the query :     :- Gt(x,y), Gt(y,x)? (is there any cycle in my programme) in bddbddb format?

Comment: I would like to express this problem in the SMTLib Format and evaluate it using Z3. edge("som1","som3").

egde("som2","som4").

egde("som4","som1").

egde("som3","som4").

path(x,y) :- edge(x,y). % x and y are strings path(x,z) :- edge(x,y), edge(y,x). :-path(x,y), path(y,x). %cyclic path.

My question is how to write the rule (or query) which detect the existence of a cycle in the relation path (this rule in basic datalog : " :- path(x,y), path(y,x)" ).